# Who decides when landing gear requires an overhaul?

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-maintenance, landing-gear

"If the landing gear on your aircraft is required to be overhauled periodically..."

So is there a case where its been decided that landing gear does not require to be overhauled?

Comment: Yes.  Most light general aviation planes do not require gear overhauls.  Most (all?) turboprops and jets do.  The manufacturer (regs?) will specify intervals.

Answer (score 1):

The aircraft manufacturer in consultation with the regulatory authority will publish a maintenance schedule that details what maintenance is required and at what interval.

For simple types the maintenance my be no more that a visual inspection and a tyre pressure check.

Comment: I am sure the  Navy  has serious inspection requirements as  high strength steel landing gear are subject to hydrogen stress cracking ( aka , hydrogen embrittlement ) in corrosive environments such as sea coasts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For commercial aircrafts, is there a regulation that requires for landing gear to be overhauled.

Comment: There's unlikely to be a specific regulation that says 'overhaul the undercarriage'. There is a regulation that says that operators must follow the manufacturer's maintenance schedule. If that calls for an undercarriage overhaul then it must be done. Exactly what that entails will vary by type and maintenance interval.

Comment: @user46429 There is no regulation directly stating that landing gear just be overhauled, only that parts on an aircraft must be airworthy, which a gear past it's TBO isn't.